# SORT XML based on Child Node text

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a XMLLike this

```
<GLLines DataTypeID="GEN" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <GLLine>
  <SYS_COMPANY_CODE>NB</SYS_COMPANY_CODE> 
  <ACCT_DOC_NUM>12720829</ACCT_DOC_NUM> 
  <ACCT_DOC_LINE>22114739</ACCT_DOC_LINE> 
  </GLLine>
   <GLLine>
  <SYS_COMPANY_CODE>NB</SYS_COMPANY_CODE> 
  <ACCT_DOC_NUM>12720827</ACCT_DOC_NUM> 
  <ACCT_DOC_LINE>22114740</ACCT_DOC_LINE> 
  </GLLine>
   <GLLine>
  <SYS_COMPANY_CODE>NB</SYS_COMPANY_CODE> 
  <ACCT_DOC_NUM>12720830</ACCT_DOC_NUM> 
  <ACCT_DOC_LINE>22114739</ACCT_DOC_LINE> 
  </GLLine>
   <GLLine>
  <SYS_COMPANY_CODE>NB</SYS_COMPANY_CODE> 
  <ACCT_DOC_NUM>12720830</ACCT_DOC_NUM> 
  <ACCT_DOC_LINE>22114738</ACCT_DOC_LINE> 
  </GLLine>
</GLLines>
```

I want to sort according to the acct DOC NUM and acct doc line .I tried XSLT but I don't know how to do it .so I'm getting wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an *identity transformation* that just copies the input to output unchanged.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can add a specific template for the `GLLines` element to sort its children

```
<xsl:template match="GLLines">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="GLLine">
      <!-- sort first on the ACCT_DOC_NUM -->
      <xsl:sort select="ACCT_DOC_NUM" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
      <!-- for lines with the same doc num, sort by line -->
      <xsl:sort select="ACCT_DOC_LINE" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is still dissplaying as text not as XML .I'm opening in IE

Comment: This is i gave in the xml document <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>

Comment: @user2945777 if you're doing the transformation in a browser then you'll probably need to transform it to some kind of HTML representation rather than simply re-ordering the original XML.  A browser will only show the XML tree structure if there's _no_ stylesheet, once you provide a stylesheet the browser assumes that you are transforming the XML into something that it knows how to render properly.

Comment: I did through vbscript to transform still not working .

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to do this automatically during an API call which returns an XML?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">  
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="ACCT_DOC_NUM"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried but i'm not able to achieve it .I'm not able to retrieve in the XML format and sorting also wrong

Comment: Can you post your xsl?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  
   
    <xsl:sort select="ACCT_DOC_NUM" order="ascending" />
    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: It is still dissplaying as text not as XML .I'm opening in IE