# Sort Parent Node based on child values and sort inside the node according to value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to sort a x ml according to child value(Invoice number ) and in turn  sort inside a child node(Description) according to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportingDocumentCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID></ReporterID>
      <TransactionDate></TransactionDate>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>3</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
</ReportingDocument>
<ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID></ReporterID>
      <TransactionDate></TransactionDate>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>8</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
</ReportingDocument>
</ReportingDocumentCollection>
```

Expected  after the transformation i need this code .i tried im not getting the right xslt please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportingDocumentCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID></ReporterID>
      <TransactionDate></TransactionDate>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>8</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
</ReportingDocument>
<ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID></ReporterID>
      <TransactionDate></TransactionDate>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>3</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
</ReportingDocument>
</ReportingDocumentCollection>
```

Comment: Could you post a proper input XML, it doesn't have a root element, also "Description" element(with value 3) isn't closed properly.

Comment: Please check i made the changes

Answer (score 2):

Use `xsl:sort` and separate templates that match the exceptions to the simple identity transform process.

You could have studied Ian's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601040/sort-xml-based-on-child-node-text?answertab=votes#tab-top) and slightly adapted it to fit your needs. Always make sure that your question *builds upon* the solution to your last question.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ReportingDocumentCollection">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportingDocument">
            <xsl:sort select="InvoiceProperties/InvoiceNumber" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="InvoiceProperties">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceNumber"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceLines">
            <xsl:sort select="Description" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'InvoiceNumber' and name() != 'InvoiceLines']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportingDocumentCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID/>
      <TransactionDate/>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>8</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
   </ReportingDocument>
   <ReportingDocument>
      <ReporterID/>
      <TransactionDate/>
      <InvoiceProperties>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>2</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
         <InvoiceLines>
            <Description>3</Description>
         </InvoiceLines>
      </InvoiceProperties>
   </ReportingDocument>
</ReportingDocumentCollection>
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't bother with the sort order because I suspect that Description is probably not really numeric

Comment: I agree - still, judging from the input XML, it might be a numeric value with an unfortunate name.

Comment: HI gibson There will some more child nodes in the invoice properties .how to bring that nodes also.Now im getiing only invoice number

Comment: This is not Gibson, but I have edited my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to change most of the elements, an identity transformation is your sensible starting point here. Splitting into several templates  will make this easier to use, understand and maintain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!-- identity transform to copy input to output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy input not but sort child nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="ReportingDocumentCollection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="InvoiceProperties/InvoiceNumber"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy InvoiceNumber to output first and then sort InvoiceLines elements -->
    <xsl:template match="InvoiceProperties">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceNumber"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceLines">
                <xsl:sort select="Description"/>

            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this to your input will give almost your output. I assumed that you didn't wish to shuffle the `InvoiceNumber` elements.

Comment: HI gibson There will some more child nodes in the invoice properties .how to bring that nodes also.Now im getiing only invoice number